# Apache web server is always sending this response: 500 internal server error at HTTP POST

Tags: apache2, webdav, mod-dav-svn

I am getting this error on an existing server. No configuration change. Suddenly, it happened. The log shows nothing, except something similar to the following:

```
10.10.10.11 - - [28/Oct/2011:01:01:08 +0800] "POST /notexist HTTP/1.1" 500 50 "-" "PECL::HTTP/1.7.1 (PHP/5.3.8)"
```

Until now I figured out that it is occurring only while using HTTP POST, it does not seem to be related to any CGI or PHP script.

I've recompiled Apache but the problem still exists. I wrote a script to visit a none exist URI of the server by using GET and POST. While requesting a GET, apache response 404, but for a POST, its response is a 500 error immediately.

Can anyone let me know what can I do? 
I am using FreeBSD and the Apache is compiled by using event MPM. 
Thanks in advance for any help.

PS. I've found it is related to subversion 1.7.1, While I reinstalled subversion 1.6.17 port, Apache seems to be working again. I am sorry to post this question here, maybe I should report this problem to FreeBSD subversion port administrator. It's weird because it doesn't happen when I upgrade to subversion 1.7.1, and it happened when there is no configuration change.

Comment: Does it only happen on errors? Did someone change an ErrorDocument lately?

Comment: Thanks for reply. No configuration change, and I just found it is related to DAV. Because if I remove DAV modules totally, Apache works. But I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2011-10/0457.shtml. It is a confirmed bug in Subversion 1.7.0 and 1.7.1. It's fixed in Subversion trunk with r1187695 which is proposed to be included in a following 1.7.x-release (see http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/branches/1.7.x/STATUS).

Comment: +1 for using a picture of Scorpius as your avatar, and providing a good answer